# error: list indices must be indtegers, not str

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, database

```
fields = ["date", "time", "a_x", "a_y", "a_z", "roll", "pitch", "yaw", "ug_x", "ug_y", "ug_z", "o2", "hyd", "bpm"]

import csv

f = open("data.TXT")


dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(), delimiters=' ')


f.seek(0)

reader = csv.reader(f, dialect)

rows = []

obj = {}

for row in reader:
  for i, field in enumerate(fields):
    obj[field] = row[i]
    if field == "a_x":
        obj[field] = float(row[i])
    elif field == "a_y":
        obj[field] = float(row[i])
    elif field == "a_z":
        obj[field] = float(row[i])
    elif field == "roll":
        obj[field] = float(row[i])
    elif field == "pitch":
        obj[field] = float(row[i])
    elif field == "yaw":
        obj[field] = float(row[i])
    elif field == "ug_x":
        obj[field] = float(row[i])
    elif field == "ug_y":
        obj[field] = float(row[i])
    elif field == "ug_z":
        obj[field] = float(row[i])
    elif field == "o2":
        obj[field] = int(row[i])
    elif field == "hyd":
        obj[field] = int(row[i])
    elif field == "bpm":
        obj[field] = int(row[i])
    else:
        obj[field] = str(row[i])
  rows.append(obj)


import requests
requests.get("http://localhost:5000/api/players")


for obj in rows:
    # *** Here is the error ***
    row["player_id"] = ['03fd6907-64fc-46e7-b1f2-38af96c48037']
    requests.post("http://localhost:5000/api/impact")
```

The error occurs in the second to last line of code, as indicated by a comment. The code is intended to upload information from a text file to a database, changing the data types match a schema written in a separate file.

I am not sure of the source of the error in line 56, that the list indices must be integers, not str, or how to fix it.

Comment: That monster of an `if` statement could be replaced by `if field in ["a_x", "a_y", ...]: obj[field] = float(row[i]) elif field in ["o2", ...]: obj[field] = int(row[i]): else: ...`.

Comment: @chepner:  Good point.  Added that to my answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski  taking your suggestions and implementing

for obj in rows:
    obj["player_id"] = ['03fd6907-64fc-46e7-b1f2-38af96c48037']

i receive the error "'str' object does not support item assignment'"

Comment: In my answer I did forget to include `rows.append(obj)` in my rewritten loop, but I don't think that's the issue you're having.  What that error message is saying is that `rows` contains strings, not dictionaries.  I can't see in your code where you append a string to `rows` so I'm not sure where that's occurring.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I believe that standard format for the csv file import in the library i am using puts the data into strings.  This code is simply attempting to reassign data types according to their field. in another file, there is a schema with the data types specified

Comment: That's not quite what I mean.  You are taking strings and storing them in a dictionary and then storing the dictionaries in a list (`rows`).  So when you pull an `obj` out of `rows` you should be getting a dictionary.  The error message says you have a string.  The only way for that to happen is that you put a string into `rows` rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
for obj in rows:
    row["player_id"] = ['03fd6907-64fc-46e7-b1f2-38af96c48037']
```

The loop variable is called `obj` but you are trying to access `row`.  `row` is a list left over from a previous loop (`for row in reader:`).  Change `row` to `obj` and the problem should go away:

```
for obj in rows:
    obj["player_id"] = ['03fd6907-64fc-46e7-b1f2-38af96c48037']
```

Also, it is a bug to define `obj = {}` outside of the `for row in reader` loop.  You will keep mutating the same dictionary and all `obj` in `rows` will be identical because they will all be references to the same object.

I would rewrite that loop as:

```
float_fields = {'a_x', 'a_y', 'a_z', 'roll', 'pitch', 'yaw', 'ug_x', 'ug_y', 'ug_z'}
int_fields = {'o2', 'hyd', 'bpm'}
for row in reader:
    obj = {} # moved inside loop
    for item, fieldname in zip(row, fields):
        if fieldname in float_fields:
            obj[fieldname] = float(item)
        elif fieldname in int_fields:
            obj[fieldname] = int(item)
        else:
            obj[fieldname] = str(item)  
    rows.append(obj)
```